# sqalchemy + postgresql: casting a uuid to text and matching with like

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, uuid

How can I convert a uuid to text and match using the `like` operator? E.g I want to do following in sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id::text like '%0c%';
```

PS: Column definition is

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
        default=uuid4,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cast](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=cast#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) function

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
with Session() as s:
    results = s.scalars(
        sa.select(MyModel).where(
            sa.cast(MyModel.id, sa.TEXT).like(f'%{fragment}%')
        )
    )
```

`id::text` in Postgresql is shorthand<sup>*</sup> for cast:

```
with x as (select gen_random_uuid() as uu)
select uu::text, 
       cast(uu as text), 
       uu::text = cast(uu as text) as "Equals?" from x;
                  uu                  │                  uu                  │ Equals? 
══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╪═════════
 b23efe1b-fb05-4d8a-92a3-59339d2ea0f4 │ b23efe1b-fb05-4d8a-92a3-59339d2ea0f4 │ t
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Well, [mostly...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/280410/151124)